# Sagemaker tensorflow endpoint not calling the input_handler when being invoked for a prediction

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I'm deploying a `tensorflow.serving` endpoint with a custom `inference.py` script via the `entry point` parameter

```
model = Model(role='xxx',
              framework_version='2.2.0',
              entry_point='inference.py',
              model_data='xxx')

predictor = model.deploy(instance_type='xxx',
                         initial_instance_count=1,
                         endpoint_name='xxx')
```

inference.py constains an `input_handler` and an `output_handler` functions, but when i call predict with:

```
model = Predictor(endpoint_name='xxx')
url = 'xxx'

input = {
    'instances': [url]
}

predictions = model.predict(input)
```

I'm getting the following `error`:

*botocore.errorfactory.ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from model with message "{"error": "Failed to process element: 0 of 'instances' list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON Value: "xxx" Type: String is not of expected type: float" }"*

It seems the function is never calling the `input_handler` function in inference.py script. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Can you share the `inference.py` script as well? What type of model is this?

Comment: Hi @YoavZimmerman, its a tensorflow.serving model. My inference.py contains the function input_handler and output_handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem thanks to AWS support:

I was creating an endpoint that already had an endpoint configuration with the same name and the new configuration wasn't being utilized.

Comment: Do you mean the input_fn()? I am suddenly getting the same error and I am not sure why. This worked before. Could you elaborate what do you mean by "had an endpoint configuration with the same name"?

Comment: So you are trying to deploy an endpoint with the same name as previously. Check the existing endpoint configurations and delete them.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding another possible cause for this error message, since it took me some time to resolve this.

I was using different sagemaker api versions (1.x and 2.x).

The name of the handler has changed from input_fn() to input_handler() for newer sagemaker tf containers.

Therefore the input_fn() was never called and the special input type never handled.

For details see: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/upgrade_from_legacy.html

Maybe this helps someone.